# mvc bootstrap datepicker with editor template not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I try to use implement bootstrap v3 datetimepicker in my mvc project but its not working.
below is my editor templates.

> @model DateTime?     
>   
>         @Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("d") : String.Empty)

> ```
> $(function() {
>     // target only the input in this editor template
>     $('#datepicker').datetimepicker();
> }); </script>
> ```

i had inculded bootstrap datetimepicker script on my _layout.chtml but seem like it cant function

> ```
> <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
> <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
> ```

this is my view

> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
>               
>                   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
>
> ```
>             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
>         </div>
>     </div>
> ```

It only come out as normal datetimepicker if i set it as

> ```
>     [DataType(DataType.Date)]
>     public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
> ```

Comment: Why are you including both the min and non-min version?  That's wrong.

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)` generates an textbox with `id="EndDate"`. Your script is targeting an element with `id="datepicker"`

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not have to include both min.js  and .js Remove one.
2. Add ~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css for CSS

   ```
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Palce holder of your choice" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
   ```

Rest of the code will work on once u initialize it

```
$(function() {
  // target only the input in this editor template
  $('#datepicker').datetimepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many bootstrap datetimepickers to date. so, you have to specify the correct datetimepicker you're using. 
if its this - http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

then, include

- include moment.js file - http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js
- get rid of one of the datetimepicker javascript files
  (either ~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js or ~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js)
- include datetimepicker css file.
- add this script in your view file.

  $(function() {$('#ID_of_the_Input').datetimepicker();});

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(function() {
    // target only the input in this editor template
    $('#EndDate').datetimepicker();
});
```